# Laravel 4 - route is not defined, on redirect

Tags: php, routes, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to setup a simple redirect after a login.
The logging in part works but the redirect fails because it says the route doesn't exist.

This is my routes file:

```
Route::any('/', array('uses' => 'UsersController@login'));

Route::any('/manage', array('uses' => 'AdminController@showWelcome'));
```

And the route works fine if i go to http://example.com/manage .. the logo of laravel is there, and my other page is fine as well.

But when i do:

```
Redirect::route('/manage');
```

the page dies saying:

```
Route [/manage] not defined
```

Anybody have an idea?

Comment: try `Redirect::to('/manager')`

Comment: i tried that, but then it's just returning to the page i already am on

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should use the route name when you are using `Redirect::route` method and in this case you have to declare the route using a name, i.e.

```
Route::any('/manage', array('as' => 'manage', 'uses' => 'AdminController@showWelcome'));
```

Here, `as` value is name of the `route`, so, now you can use

```
return Redirect::route('manage'); // 'manage' is the name of the route to redirect
```

Or, alternatively, you can use `Redirect::to('url')` method, i.e.

```
return Redirect::to('/manage'); // '/manage' is the url to redirect
```

Check [Redirect to a named Route](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#redirects) and [named routes](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#named-routes).

Comment: I did what you said, but still get redirected back to my original page

Comment: Then, maybe you are already on the page that is being redirected to.

Comment: haha, no i am not, but it would be something to check, which i did as well :)

Answer (score 1):

This error "Route [manage] not defined" is because of the route name "manage" is not defined.

Route name and Route path are two different things.

And you've declared the route path as admin,

```
Route::any('manage', 'AdminController@showWelcome');
```

However,

```
return redirect()->route('manage');
```

means that you are redirecting the flow to the route named "manage".

To sort the error,

Define a route name "manage" as follows in an array defined below with 'as' => 'route_name'.

Solution :

```
Route::any('manage', [
   'as' => 'manage',
   'uses' => 'AdminController@showWelcome'
]);
```

Please refer the link : https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#named-routes

Answer (score -2):

use return Redirect::intended('mannage');